Как сделать автозагрузку приложения на Android?
Проблема следующая: хочу, чтобы мое приложение запускалось сразу после загрузки телефона. Нашел информацию, что можно прослушать BOOT_COMPLETED и после запустить нужную мне активити. Вот что получилось:
class BootUpReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val target = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(target)
    }
}

В манифест занес необходимые разрешения
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Про receiver не забыл
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>

В Logcat при запуске вижу это:
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (2473) for package com.example.video ----------------------------
2024-05-23 15:45:31.235  2473-2473  TetheringManager        com.example.video                    I  registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.video
2024-05-23 15:45:31.241  2473-2473  WM-PackageManagerHelper com.example.video                    D  Skipping component enablement for androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
2024-05-23 15:45:31.241  2473-2473  WM-Schedulers           com.example.video                    D  Created SystemJobScheduler and enabled SystemJobService
2024-05-23 15:45:31.290   544-928   ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       I  START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.video/.MainActivity} from uid 10178
2024-05-23 15:45:31.291   544-928   ActivityTaskManager     system_process                       W  Background activity start [callingPackage: com.example.video; callingUid: 10178; isCallingUidForeground: false; callingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; callingUidProcState: RECEIVER; isCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; realCallingUid: 10178; isRealCallingUidForeground: false; realCallingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; realCallingUidProcState: RECEIVER; isRealCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; originatingPendingIntent: null; isBgStartWhitelisted: false; intent: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.video/.MainActivity }; callerApp: ProcessRecord{b50321a 2473:com.example.video/u0a178}]
2024-05-23 15:45:32.755  2473-2496  System                  com.example.video                    W  A resource failed to call close. 
2024-05-23 15:45:34.604   544-2905  ActivityManager         system_process                       I  Killing 2473:com.example.video/u0a178 (adj 985): empty #17
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (2473) for package com.example.video ----------------------------

Пробовал на эмулятор Pixel 5 API 30 и устройстве Infinix X669D. В документации ничего толком не нашел, gpt предлагал 3 варианта - не помогло. На телефоне есть настройка "Управление автозапуском", так же не помогло. Видел пример с хабра, стака - результат тот же. Если запускать самостоятельно, то приложение работает великолепно.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Спасибо, однако там указано, что один из вариантов это наличие определенных служб или "В приложении есть активность, которая началась совсем недавно". Как я могу запустить свою активити, чтобы система не убила ее? Я не нашел примеров подобного кода, и не совсем понимаю теорию подобного действия. Из документации я понял, что надо взять случайный процесс, который подпадает под условия и через него уже вытянуть приложение из фона. А формулировка с активностью, которая началась недавно это вообще выглядит забавно, то есть мне надо запустить активити, чтобы запустить активити.

Не совсем понятно что вы подразумеваете в контексте Андроид под "чтобы мое приложение запускалось сразу после загрузки телефона"? Хотите чтобы пользователь обратил внимание на ваше приложение? "Display notifications instead" - говорит документация. Он кликнет и все откроется. Иначе вам на глаза пользователя не попасть.

Для начала нужно пояснить зачем вам это нужно. Это не рекомендуемое поведение и Андроид будет с вами бороться, ваше приложение не должно мешать пользователю пользоваться устройством. Вспомните сайт из которого лезут попапы - мало приятного. Единственный, наверное, вариант когда запуск активности при загрузке системы уместен - это если вы делаете приложение-оболочку (launcher). Для этого нужно указать активности специальный фильтр: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76204410/15923106 и чтобы пользователь выбрал вашу оболочку основной.

Представьте, что то, что вы хотите, исполнилось на вашем телефоне, тогда при загрузке вы увидите 100 приложений которые откроют свои окна, а вы будете лихорадочно их закрывать. Удачи!
